# How to use Set with useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `Set` with `useRef`. This is what I tried.

```
export default function App() {
  const data = useRef<Set<string>>(new Set());

  const add = () => {
    data.current = new Set([...Array.from(data.current), "Add"]);
  };

  const show = () => {
    console.log(data.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={show}>Show</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting `Set {}` when I check the value after updating. What is actually going on here?

Comment: A ref doesn't have any automatic updating, so you don't need to recreate the object. Just add to the existing set.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Where are you logging `data.current`? Is it in a subcomponent?

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.current, null, 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working correctly. The `Set {}` is just the way the console shows a set. You can see upon expand (after clicking add then show), the data is there.

The other answer about adding to the set rather than the complex spread is also true btw -- you dont need to care about immutable state transitions with refs. But this is a code smell rather than a bug. Your code still works.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I just got it. For a moment I thought it was not there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73327399/how-to-use-set-with-useref/73327529?noredirect=1#comment129496532_73327399) by [super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super)

> A ref doesn't have any automatic updating, so you don't need to recreate the object. Just add to the existing set.

```
const add = () => {
  data.current.add("Add");
};
```

Comment: [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing) You can get a link to a comment by right-clicking on the date or 'n' <time> ago text and copying the link.

Comment: Thank you! Using this from here 